# Show/Hide Markers based on property jQuery-UI-Map (Google maps API V3)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui-map

I have been developing a mapping program using jQuery-UI-Map plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). I am having an issue that I have tried to solve in MANY different ways to no avail.

I have a drop down that `onchange` should filter the markers on the map.

Here is the snippet of the code that pertains to this issue. With this code when I choose a value from the drop down all the markers are removed.

```
   $('#map').gmap().bind('init', function (evt, map) {
    $.getJSON('controllers/markers.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
            $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                'icon': "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|" + marker.projectNumber + "|004162|FFFFFF|",
                'bounds': false,
                'statusSelect': marker.status
            })
        });
        $("#statusSelect").change(function () {
            $('#map').gmap('find', 'markers', {
                'property': 'statusSelect',
                'value': $(this).val()
            },

            function (marker, found) {
                if (found) {
                    $('#map').gmap('addBounds', marker.position);
                }
                marker.setVisible(found);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the JSON that I am using:

http://designsbymitch.com/markers.json

EDIT: here is the HTML for the status drop down -

```
<select id="statusSelect">
        <option value="Created">Created</option>
        <option value="Working">Working</option>
        <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
        <option value="Task">Task</option>
        <option value="Void">Void</option>
        <option value="delete">delete</option>
        <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
        <option value="Overdue">Overdue</option>
        <option value="Invoiced">Invoiced</option>
        <option value="Non-Billable Expense">Non-Billable Expense</option>
        <option value="Billable Expense">Billable Expense</option>
        <option value="Unpaid">Unpaid</option>
        <option value="new status mitch">new status mitch</option>
        <option value="new status mitch again">new status mitch again</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem and possibly a bug in the UI, 
the property you're setting is number you should make it a string 
replace marker.status by ""+marker.status
and the same thing in your find!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're setting a custom property called `statusSelect` when you call `addMarker`, and then looking for a property called `tags` when you call `find`. Change `property: 'tags'` to `property: 'statusSelect'` and it should work.

You're also doing something rather strange when you bind your events - you're binding a new `change` event every time you create a marker, so if you have 100 markes you'll have 100 `change` event listeners, which will all fire in sequence and do the same thing. You should move `$("#statusSelect").change(...)` outside of your `$.each` function, so there's only one event handler being bound.

So, your code should read:

```
$('#map').gmap().bind('init', function (evt, map) {
    $.getJSON('controllers/markers.json', function (data) {
        $.each(data.markers, function (i, marker) {
            $('#map').gmap('addMarker', {
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                'icon': "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|" + marker.projectNumber + "|004162|FFFFFF|",
                'bounds': false,
                'statusSelect': marker.status
            })
        });
        $("#statusSelect").change(function () {
            $('#map').gmap('find', 'markers', {
                'property': 'statusSelect',
                'value': $(this).val()
            },

            function (marker, found) {
                if (found) {
                    $('#map').gmap('addBounds', marker.position);
                }
                marker.setVisible(found);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So sorry...I had tried so many things I forgot to change the property field back to the reference. I tried your code with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery UI Map's [`addMarker`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples#Example_addMarker) and [`findMarker`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/Examples#Example_findMarker) methods?